# How Uninstall pip and python

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, ubuntu-16.04, pip

I wanted to install version 3 of python and pip but instead issued

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev
```

how do I uninstall python and pip, I tried sudo apt-get uninstall but did not work, what is the correct command?

Comment: Just a note, on ubuntu you have python-pip and python3-pip, but they have different commands anyway. One is `pip` and the other is `pip3`. As such installing python-pip and python-dev is not detrimental.

Answer (score 12):

In order to remove it type:

```
sudo apt-get remove python-pip python-dev
```

If you're not sure which switch to use, you can add the `--help` switch to almost if not every Linux command to get details about the command.

Example:

```
apt-get --help
```

Comment: If you're on an aws ec2-instance you have to use yum. Anyone know the command using yum and not apt-get?

Comment: @KyleBridenstine this is partially right, if you use aws ami of Amazon Linux then since it is based on Centos, then you use yum. The equivalent in Yum is: “yum remove package_name”.

Comment: "sudo yum remove python-pip python-dev" works fine for CentOS 7

Answer (score 5):

to fully remove those you can use
`sudo apt purge python-pip python-dev` <-- this will delete all the files/directories/binaries created by that package